# In cmake how to create a regular file using the target generated

Tags: cmake

I want to create a regular file using the target generated, here is the sample code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable (write_fields #write_fields will create test.dat
    main.cpp
  )
add_custom_command ( 
    OUTPUT test.dat
    DEPENDS write_fields
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/write_fields
    VERBATIM
  )
```

But it seems that the custom command never get executed

**UPDATE:**

The following code doesn’t work either

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project(myproj)

add_executable (write_fields
    main.cpp
  )

add_custom_command ( 
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.dat
    DEPENDS write_fields
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/write_fields
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(myproj DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test.dat)
```

Comment: Common mistake: you have *command*, generating file, but don't have *target*, which depends on that file. *Command* without *target* doesn't have a sence in CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. It seem that add_custom_target can add a PHONY target. but it doesn’t work either.

Comment: You have either to add custom command with *ALL* option, so it will be built with common `make`, or use `make myproj`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) carefully:

> If `COMMAND` specifies an executable target (created by the `add_executable()` command) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time.

in other words you can use just a plain target name to execute it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)

add_executable (
    write_fields #write_fields will create test.dat
    main.cpp
  )

add_custom_command( 
    COMMAND write_fields
    OUTPUT test.dat
    DEPENDS write_fields
    VERBATIM
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. But the write_fields still doesn’t get executed

Comment: @camino, because there is no targets depending on output of this command.

Comment: @camino if you want this to be a part of your build process use `add_custom_target()` or make `test.dat` dependency of some other target

Answer (score 0):

> The second signature adds a custom command to a target such as a
>   library or executable. This is useful for performing an operation
>   before or after building the target. The command becomes part of the
>   target and will only execute when the target itself is built. If the
>   target is already built, the command will not execute.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET target
                   PRE_BUILD | PRE_LINK | POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND command1 [ARGS] [args1...]
                   [COMMAND command2 [ARGS] [args2...] ...]
                   [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                   [COMMENT comment] [VERBATIM])
```

> This defines a new command that will be associated with building the
>   specified target. When the command will happen is determined by which
>   of the following is specified:
>
> PRE_BUILD - run before all other dependencies
>
> PRE_LINK - run after other dependencies
>
> POST_BUILD - run after the target has been built

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)


add_executable (write_fields
    main.cpp
    )

add_custom_command ( 
    TARGET write_fields
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND write_fields
    VERBATIM
)
```